# How to delete Analytics property from list in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

When I look at the *Google Analytics Property* page in Webmaster Tools (where you associate a Google Analytics web property with a Webmaster Tools site), I see a list of a bunch of properties with weird names. They are test properties from when we were trying things out years ago.

I can't view them or change their name in Analytics because they don't exist there. All their profiles were deleted years ago.

Is there a way to remove these from the list in Webmaster Tools? Or, alternatively, a way to view them again in Analytics so I can give them a better name, at least.

I know this doesn't matter in the big scheme of things, but I hate clutter.

Comment: any more news? Why does Google have to be so obtuse? most of their UI to apps are less than clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to remove old, deleted, analytics setups from that list in Google Webmaster Tools.

This has been [discussed on the Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/hXszD9aKJWA/A53NjjmrxpAJ) (also [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/HanGFMF3QUo/JpLRiNA3uWsJ)).  No solution has been found, and there is no official word from Google about this bug.

You could go to those forums and press the "Me Too!" button which might get the issue onto Google's radar a bit faster.  To get the button, you will have to join the forums from the gear icon in the top left -> "Membership and email settings".

[image: google product forums me too button]

Comment: I don't see a "Me Too!" button. It seems both posts are closed due to inactivity. I guess I'm in the minority and will just have to live with it.

Comment: I added a screenshot with a red circle around the "Me Too!" button for you.

Comment: Nope. Don't see that. Do I have to join or anything?

Comment: Most likely.  I'm logged in with my Google account.  I did choose a screen name for the forums at some point.

Comment: I'm logged in to my Google account, and I can see a *Post a Question* button at the top of the Google Product forums, but no "Me Too!" button and no join button. Their site is really NOT user-friendly.

Comment: I found the join button. My settings > Membership and email settings. *My settings* is the gear icon that has the person on it (top right).